# execute program in loop bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, executable

I would like to run the executable run_ex multiple times varying some parameters (text file), but I am new to the bash scripts and I can't figure out how to do that...

```
#! /bin/bash
for ((hour=1; hour <= 9 ; hour++))
do
   printf "run executable for hour %d \n" $hour

   parameter1 ="/path1/file1_$hour.txt" 

   parameter2 = "/path2/file2_$hour.txt" 

   ./run_ex $parameter1 $parameter2

done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*spaces* are not allowed around `=` for variable assignment:

```
  parameter1 ="/path1/file1_$hour.txt" 
  #         ^
```

Write that instead:

```
  parameter1="/path1/file1_$hour.txt" 
  parameter2="/path2/file2_$hour.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [Sylvain Leroux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25055004/445221), you should also place your variables inside double-quotes to prevent word splitting and unexpected pathname expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((hour=1; hour <= 9 ; hour++))
do
    printf "run executable for hour %d \n"" $hour"

    parameter1="/path1/file1_$hour.txt" 
    parameter2="/path2/file2_$hour.txt" 

   ./run_ex "$parameter1" "$parameter2"
done
```

Also with brace expansion, you can simplify `for ((hour=1; hour <= 9 ; hour++))` as `for hour in {1..9}; do`.

See [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [Pathname or Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).